# Server returns 500 Internal Server error after trying to insert data in database using CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data to the database but I get the 500 Internal Server Error message in the console,

**What I'm trying to do?**

I'm trying to send form data using jquery with this code,

```
function submit_form (form) {
  var url      = $('form#my_form').attr("action");
  var formData = {};
  $('form#my_form').find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
    swal(data);
  });
}
```

From the controller in `codeigniter`, this method is responsible for receiving data that was sent,

```
  public function add () {
    $data   = $this->_accept();
    $result = $this->company_model->add( $data );
    echo $result;
  }
```

Receiving data was fine, but when I passed it to the model,

```
  public function add ($data) {
    $result = $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data);
    return $result;
  }
```

And trying to insert the data into the database, A message return that 500 Internal Server Error, I have no Idea about the solution, I'm trying anything, until I have no idea.

Anyone having an Idea?

Comment: Enable $config['log_threshold'] (level ERROR) and re-run this case. After that, you need to checking error logs in application/logs to view the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several reasons for this error

```
    1. Please check your table_name that you are passing.i.e. $this->table_name...
    2. Check your data, which you are inserting, means string/characters must be in single quotes and numerical in without quotes.
    3. Check your database table fields and inserting array values. Inserting array values must be respective to the database table fields.
```

Comment: I already did like that, because it work without using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable debug profiler to find what cause this.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html